# wrong date range is listed

Tags: sql, datetime, time

Other than the date range I'm giving is listed in your opinion how can I help you to solve?

1 July -12 July between is not listed

https://i.hizliresim.com/od7YzX.jpg

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                         s.A, CONVERT(varchar, d.timein, 104) AS G
FROM            DATABASE.table1 AS a INNER JOIN
                         DATABASE.table2 AS b ON a.x = b.y INNER JOIN
                         DATABASE.dbo.table3 AS c ON b.b = c.d INNER JOIN
                         DATABASE.dbo.table4 AS e ON c.f = e.r INNER JOIN
                         DATABASE.table5 AS d ON e.t = d.u INNER JOIN
                         DATABASE.table6 AS s ON a.fr = s.rf INNER JOIN
                         DATABASE.table7 AS si ON d.er = si.pr INNER JOIN
                         DATABASE.table8 AS i ON si.dd = i.gt INNER JOIN
                         DATABASE.table9 AS ck ON s.mkk = ck.pxx
WHERE         (CONVERT(varchar, d.timein, 104) BETWEEN '01.07.2019' AND '12.07.2019')
```

Comment: Can't understand your question bro

Comment: Sample Input data with O/p will help

Comment: date comes out of my date range

Comment: example '01.05.2019'

Comment: because ı want to list BETWEEN '01.07.2019' AND '12.07.2019'

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date functions and operators are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question add the [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) as plain text. The link you included just gives a "403 forbidden" error for me - precisely the reason why a question should be self-contained and not linking to external sites for essential information.

Answer (score 1):

try to use date format as 'yyyy-MM-dd'

```
BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare string dates, compare dates.

```
WHERE d.timein BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-12'
```

Note that this will return dates between `2019-07-01 00:00:00` and `2019-07-12 00:00:00`, so you may need to use `2019-07-13` or `2019-07-12 23:59:59`

When you compare strings, it compares characters from left to right, so, for example, `10.12.2018` is between `01.07.2019` and `12.07.2019`, because `10` is between `01` and `12`